# Guid.Tostring() gives a different representation than UUID_TO_CHAR in my database

Tags: c#, firebird, uuid, guid, firebird2.5

I'm using a Firebird database with UUIDs as primary keys but I've run into the following problem:

The textual representation of the same Guid in my C# application differs from that of the database. I'm getting the textual representation in the database with the `UUID_TO_CHAR` function and in my C# application using `Guid.ToString()`.

The difference comes from the way the Firebird database interprets the UUIDs vs the .net framework, I believe they read them with a [different byte ordering](http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-376)

So for example a guid in the database looks like this:

```
FADE3E40-6227-5B40-BBB9-8492859EBA66
```

And the same guid in my C# application looks like this:

```
403edefa-2762-405b-bbb9-8492859eba66
```

Is there a way to either display them in my database the same way they're displayed in C#. Or vice versa?

Is there a way to do a conversion when getting them from, and putting them into, the database so I don't have to use a format anywhere?

Comment: It's not ADO.NET or C#. That's the way GUIDs are *generated* in Windows since they started using GUIDs. I'm not sure if that goes back to Windows 1.0 (1985). In any case you shouldn't be comparing, using or displaying the textual representation of a GUID. How are you using this GUID and why is it a problem? Where is it generated?

Comment: Guid is generated in my C# application. Ofcourse i need to compare them, if there's a problem with one of the components i need to know which one if i want to check anything in the database. Thus i need to log the identification of said component.

Comment: You don't need the textual representation for the comparison. Compare the *values* in the query.

Comment: That is Microsoft for you, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Encoding : _"Other systems, notably Microsoft's marshalling of UUIDs in their COM/OLE libraries, use a mixed-endian format, whereby the first three components of the UUID are little-endian, and the last two are big-endian."_

Comment: @MarkRotteveel actually, that is UUIDs for you. It's the oldest surviving company that uses UUIDs. The others are dead - in fact many Apollo engineers moved to Microsoft. If you read a bit farther down, both types are standardised as `variant 1` and `varian 2` with `variant 1` being the older, `many identifiers generated and used in Microsoft Windows software and referred to as "GUIDs" are standard variant 1 RFC 4122/DCE 1.1 network byte-order UUIDs, rather than little-endian variant 2 UUIDs`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos how? I've got a .txt file to log my guids in, I want them to be sort of readable.

Comment: Those FB functions seem to work incorrectly, but because of backward compatibility they would probably be left as they are. One might probably use some UDF library to get another textual representation http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3887 http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/CORE-3238

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To get the same representation as in firebird - convert all bytes of guid as is to hex:

```
BitConverter.ToString(guid.ToByteArray()).Replace("-", "")
```

You can optionally put "-" between groups if necessary, for example like this:

```
static class Extensions {
    public static string ToFirebirdString(this Guid guid) {
        var raw = BitConverter.ToString(guid.ToByteArray()).Replace("-", "");
        return $"{raw.Substring(0, 8)}-{raw.Substring(8, 4)}-{raw.Substring(12,4)}-{raw.Substring(16, 4)}-{raw.Substring(20)}";
    }
}
```

Comment: I've decided to do it the other way around, i'm creating a method to replace the UUID_TO_CHAR function but your answer is correct and would be acceptable for my question.